# Durable Azure Function created with .Net6 (VS2022) debugging locally giving Source Not Found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Durable Function with below versions.

.Net=> .Net6

Azure Function=> V4

Microsft.Azure.WebExtensions.DurableTask => 2.7.2

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions=>4.1.1

While trying to run boilerplate code created with function, its asking to download source link file from internet.

If I don't download source link file from internet its showing Source Not Found tab while debugging for (FunctionInvoker.cs, FunctionExecutor.cs etc) cs files.

If I download source and continuing debugging the control going inside the cs files downloaded from the source link.

Is download and continue debugging is the right option and how to suppress the debugging in the source link downloaded file, as I am not interested in every time debug from SourceLink Files.

Please suggest better options if there are any apart from this to create durable function.
Any quick help much appreciated. Thank you in Advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

*We have tried to create Durable Azure function in our environment and tested successfully* ,You can follow the below workaround:-

- Created Durable function using `.net 6` using VS 2022 v17.2.1  with same configuration as yours.

[image]

- we have the following versions in our `.csproj`

[image]

- Make sure that [***`Azure storage emulator`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) has installed and running at your local.

***OUTPUT DETAILS OF RUNNING FUNCTION:-***

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***CREATE DURABLE FUNCTION USING VS 2022***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-visualstudio). & [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348395/source-link-will-download-from-the-internet) for similar issue.

***Alternatively***, you can refer this to update the vs version and azurite version  as mentioned in this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/1447#issuecomment-1121141439) issue.